# Jenkins Failed to advertise SSH port

Tags: nginx, ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install plugins through the Jenkins plugins manager. I am setting up Jenkins for the first time. When I click install it returns a 500 error and i'm not sure why. I am running jenkins with Nginx. When I check the jenkins.log I see:

```
May 07, 2015 6:35:29 AM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.PortAdvertiser getEndpoint
WARNING: Failed to advertise SSH port
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: jenkins.mysitename.com
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
        at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.PortAdvertiser.getEndpoint(PortAdvertiser.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3500)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
        at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.PortAdvertiser.httpHeaders.run(httpHeaders.groovy:3)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:74)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:62)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
        at hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$1.reportException(InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:27)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.reportException(CompressionFilter.java:77)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Nginx error.log:

```
2015/05/07 06:35:29 [crit] 11098#0: *286 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/9/00/0000000009" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: (ip address), server: _, request: "GET /pluginManager/available HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pluginManager/available", host: "jenkins.mysitename.com", referrer: "http://jenkins.mysitename.com/pluginManager/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by editing my nginx.conf file to mimic the example here: 
[Jenkins behind NGinX reverse proxy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name jenkins.domain.tld;

  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout   150;
    proxy_send_timeout      100;
    proxy_read_timeout      100;
    proxy_buffers           4 32k;
    client_max_body_size    8m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not specified the full Jenkins URL in the system config.

Under Manage Jenkins → Configure System → Jenkins Location → Jenkins URL, you should enter `http://jenkins.mysitename.com:8080/` (for example) rather than just the hostname `jenkins.mysitename.com`.